# WPF Capture a Textbox onBlur event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a textbox in my WPF Application. I am used to web development where you can capture the `onBlur` events with JavaScript. Is this possible also in my WPF app?

All I am trying to do is NOT have a "Save" button, but to just update the database when they are finished modifying the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you want to do it using an event?

In WPF, when you want to update your back logic when you lose focus on a control, you usually use a Binding with [UpdateSourceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) equal to `LostFocus`

Just as example

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding myBackLogicText, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"  />
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you read all available events descriptions?
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.aspx

I guess you are looking for **LostFocus** event but you should look for the one that best fits your solution.